# Using pandas left merge not bringing expected results

Tags: pandas, merge, left-join

I have two dataframes, both have a single column 'ITEM''
I am trying to achieve this, do a suitable merge so the result are only the values from the left dataframe, that match the second and leave the rest out. I read and tried several solutions and thought a left merge will do the trick but it's not working

```
   import pandas as pd

   # filenames = ['newsc.csv','oldsc.csv']
   # newsc has the label ITEM
   '''         values 
   400012
   400016
   400021
   400028
   400038
   400042
   400050
   400056
   400084
   400088
   400105
   400148
   400154
   400173
   400181
   400184
   400193
   400197
   400202
   400209
   423316
   429247
   441835
   446011
   446012
   447164
   454086
   457076
   459524
   467432
   503013
   514979
   524815
   535084
   541730
   545113
   547630
   548622
   '''
   # oldsc also uses the same label 'ITEM'
   '''    values
   400015
   400016
   400019
   400021
   400028
   400033
   400037
   400038
   400042
   400050
   400056
   400057
   400061
   400063
   400068
   400069
   400073
   400077
   400084
   400091
   400092
   400097
   400102
   400105
   400113
   400118
   400121
   400122
   400126
   400127
   400128
   400132
   400133
   400134
   400141
   400148
   400153
   400154
   '''


   # I'm reading the above values from both csv files to compare what 
   # values in df1 are present in df2

   df = pd.read_csv('newsc.csv')

   df1 = pd.read_csv('oldsc.csv')

   df3 = pd.merge(df, df1, left_on='ITEM', right_on='ITEM', how ='left')
   print(df3.head(13))
```

I was expecting to get these

```
   400016
   400021
   400028
   400038
   400042
   400050
   400056
   400084
   400105
   400148
   400154
```

Instead I'm getting these results

```
   ITEM
   0  400012
   1  400016
   2  400021
   3  400028
   4  400038
   5  400042
   6  400050
   7  400056
   8  400084
   9  400088     
   10 400105
   11 400148
   12 400154
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an inner join, not left.

```
>>> pd.merge(df,df1, on="ITEM")
```

That should do what you need, since the `inner` join is the default (no need to specify it explicitly)

Comment: ok. Thanks! that did the trick! @Danail Petrov